# Get the absolute difference between elements of a circular array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

Let's say I have a array like l = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8]

where the n<sup>th</sup> element represents the distance between the n<sup>th</sup> and n+1<sup>th</sup> object.

I want to find the distance between any two objects, and I used this code for this:

```
def dis(l_list, index1, index2, mylist):
    m = mylist.index(index1)
    n = mylist.index(index2)
    i=0
    j=0
    if n > m:
        while n >= m:
            i = i + mylist[m]
            m = m + 1
    elif n < m:
        while n <= m:
            i = i + mylist[n]
            n = n + 1
    else:
        return(0)
    j = mylist[n] % l_mylist
    print(abs(i - j))

l_mylist = input()
l_mylist = int(l_mylist)

mylist = []

mylist = list(map(int, input().split()))

i,j = input().split()
i, j=int(i), int(j)
dis(l_mylist, i, j, mylist)
```

but I am still getting the wrong output. Can anyone please point out where I am wrong?

Comment: You should clarify what output you *are* getting and what output you expect.

Comment: Let's say my array is [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]. If I input 3 and 6, then it should give output as 12.

Comment: I added an updated version of my code here : https://pastebin.com/jNSYMPJ3

Comment: @ShaoXin Still a bit difficult to understand what you expect, could you write down a clear example (all arguments, the expect answer and why).

Comment: How do you get `12` as an output?

Comment: The program takes input like this:  *Size of Array*  *Elements of array*  *The objects, in between which you want to calculate the distance*    So, For example,    First Line : 8    Second Line : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8   Third Line : 3 6    Then output should be 12, because distance between 3rd and 6th object = 3+4+5 = 12.

Comment: So you are just trying to `sum(mylist[3-1:6-1]) == 12` (subtract 1 because indexes start at 0)

Comment: Kinda, yes. But since this is a circular array, the distance can be calculated counterclockwise too.

Comment: And what do you actually get as output from the code in your question? And waht are m and n for inputs 3 and 6?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sum around a potentially circular list. You can use a `collections.deque()` to rotate the list, e.g.:

```
from collections import deque

def dist(l, i1, i2):
    d = deque(l)
    d.rotate(-i1)
    return sum(list(d)[:i2-i1]))

In []:
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
dist(l, 3-1, 6-1)     # 3, 4, 5

Out[]:
12

In []:
dist(l, 6-1, 3-1)     # 6, 7, 8, 1, 2

Out[]:
24
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def distance(first_index, second_index, my_list):
    temp_list = my_list + my_list
    if (first_index > second_index):
        first_index += len(my_list)
        requested_sum = sum(my_list[second_index-1:first_index-1])
    else:
        requested_sum = sum(my_list[first_index-1:second_index-1])
    return requested_sum
```

If I understood you correctly, then this should do the trick.

There are much more compact and efficient ways to do this, but this is the simplest and easiest to understand in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks. This works well. I didn't knew about sum function.